# Posting a link (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form that allows users to enter comments currently. It only allows plain text.

I want to add a button that lets users post a link. I would want them to be able to click the "link" button to bring up a new text box to enter the link. and then combine that link and whatever they entered in the plain comment text box into one comment with the link at the bottom when they click a submit button. The submit button currently works for the plain text.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Prop1 { get;  set; }

    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

But on the server you need to remove all dangerous tags. More details: [Understanding Request Validation in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/02/19/understanding-request-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)